# Calculating the modulus of a large number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am studying for a quiz in discrete structures. How can I calculate 2^50 (mod5)? I can calculate the result with smaller numbers with the use of a calculator but I can not do it with a large number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a number `N` = `5X + Y`, where N, X and Y are whole numbers (i.e. `N mod 5 = Y`). It would follow then that since `2N = 2(5X + Y) = 10x + 2Y`, that `2N mod 5 = 2Y mod 5`.

Similarily, since 2^50 can be rewritten as ((2^5)^5)^2:

`2^50 mod 5 = ((2^5 mod 5)^5 mod 5)^2 mod 5`

`2^50 mod 5 = ((2)^5 mod 5)^2 mod 5`

`2^50 mod 5 = (2)^2 mod 5`

`2^50 mod 5 = 4`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the fact that `if (2^x = t)(mod A) then (2^(x*y) = t^y)(mod A)`.

Hence, we have:

```
2^2  = (-1) (mod 5) which means
2^50 = (-1)^25(mod 5)
     = -1 (mod 5) (which is the same as 4 (mod 5))
```

Using actual computation, we see `2^50 = 1125899906842624 = -1(mod 5)`.